# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I am trying to connect my android client to gmail server using asmack android jar but I am getting a runtime error NoClassDefFoundError on `ConnectionConfiguration`. I am using the following code

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com",5222,"gmail.com");
    XMPPConnection connection= new XMPPConnection(config);
```

Even I use only `XMPPConnection connection= new XMPPConnection("gmail.com");` it still throws NoClassDefFoundError on `XMPPConnection`. 
asmack-android-5.jar file in the project. I have even tried to run this application using different smack jars but could not succeed. There is no build error but a runtime error and visible in eclipse DDMS. By da way I am using eclipse.

I have read the other thread but still not able to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you init the static smack code before using smack? What version of asmack are you using?

Comment: i am using asmack-android-5.jar. I have also used smack3_0_3. None of them worked. I have tested smack3_0_3 in my java application without any problem but it doesnt work in android. I assume that its just a class loading problem in android.

Comment: Unfortunately `asmack-android-5.jar` could refer to a dozen different asmack's. Where did you get it from?

Comment: I have solved the problem. The smack jar file must be in the libs directory. It will not work if you add it as an external jar in your project. You have to manually move the jar to the project libs directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have a folder in your project called `libs` and that the smack jar is in there.  Android will automatically load libraries from the `libs` folder. The jars will automatically appear under "Android Dependencies" in your Eclipse project after refreshing.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Smack jar is under reference libraries not in the libs because I added it as an external jar from build project tab in eclipse. Do I need to move this jar to libs folder? If it is necessary what is the reason?

Answer (score 2):

I do encounter the same problem. It takes lots of time to solve it. 
First, you may open the Java path build window. Then Choose the Order and Export tab. Make the asmack jar checked. Up the jar to the top.